# Load Aspect pointcut expression from properties file

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I am using aspectj  in my project and I m trying to load pointcut expression from properties file, something like below.

```
@Pointcut(
      "execution("LOAD THIS EXPRESSSION FROM PROPERTIES FILE")
  public void pointCut() {
    // Pointcut definition 
  }
```

what all possible options that I have, except defining aspect in xml file?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot. Annotations need to have static values.

Answer (score 0):

Like M. Deinum said, unfortunately, this is not possible as ***annotation need static values***.

However, you can implement AOP programmatically. Which *should* enable you to make it more configurable.

Have a look at

- [Coding AOP programmatically](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch09s07.html)
- [Spring AOP - Proxy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springaop/springaop_proxy.htm)